# I'm trying to connect to oracle data base from django and i got this erorr(ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel )

Tags: django, oracle

I'am using django 4.1 and oracle 9.2 ,

when i'm trying to connect to oracle from django , i got this erorr

```
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

this is my connection

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': '***',
        'USER': '***',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': '***',
        'PORT': '***',
    }
}
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: This is an *extremely* generic error and could have literally hundreds of causes. It just means that your dedicated server process on the DB server has died for some reason or is not responding. Were there any other error messages? Does this happen on connection, or after connection is established? If after, does it happen consistently for any particular SQL command? Is there any additional detail in the database alert log? Is there a dump or trace file on the server? Have you tried searching this site or the My Oracle Support Communities site for ORA-03113 questions?

Comment: From Django 4.0, support is for Oracle DB 19 and higher.  See the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#oracle-notes) "Django supports Oracle Database Server versions 19c and higher. Version 7.0 or higher of the cx_Oracle Python driver is required.".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have properly specified version of Oracle DB where you try to connect - version "9.2"? That is very old, no, VERY OLD version of Oracle Database, literally 20+ years old. Means, if there was no typo and version is really 9.2, then error you encountered is just from incompatibility between Oracle DB server and Oracle Client used by Django (can be Oracle Client / Oracle Instant Client, or Python module `cx_Oracle`). Means, all these different clients are too new for work with so old Oracle Database. As a result, during attempt to establish connection, you get error `"ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel"`.

BTW exact version of Oracle Database consists of 4 figures (or even 5 figures), not 2 figures like you mentioned - "9.2". In case of 9.2 release, version of Oracle DB can be 9.2.0.1 (first one) and up to 9.2.0.8.

In order to resolve issue with connection, you have to either try to find very old, compatible version of Oracle Client or Python module `cx_Oracle` (if such version even exists), or, which is much more preferable way - upgrade your Oracle DB to some current version, like 19c or 21c.

Comment: If the version mismatch was the problem, I would expect connection to fail cleanly with an ORA error saying there was a version problem.  But the points about the age of 9.2, and about finding compatible versions are accurate.  Luckily current versions of cx_Oracle (and python-oracledb) can work with Oracle Client 11.2.  This Oracle client version can connect to Oracle Database 9.2